# Change Focus from an input element to the dynamic content place holder div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In the following html, the focus is on the **sample_input** element after the page loaded. After the value is typed and enter button is pressed ajax requests are sent to the server and the response of the ajax request is appended to the **my_dynamic_content** div. At this point how to change the focus to the dynamic content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    </head>
  <body>
    <script src="/javascripts/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <div>
      <input id="sample_input" type="text" placeholder="Type URL" autofocus="autofocus"/>
    </div>
    <div id="my_dynamic_content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tried the following in the **on enter** pressed callback function which did not work

```
$('#my_dynamic_content').blur();
$("body").attr('tabindex', -1).focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a tabindex value to the div and then a method of checking when the enter key is pressed. The easiest way to do that is to wrap the input in a form with an id then capture the onsubmit event and prevent the form from redirecting the page then assign focus to the div

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/n2jqf2va/2/))

```js
$("#myFancyForm").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#my_dynamic_content").focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form id="myFancyForm">
    <input id="sample_input" type="text" placeholder="Type URL" autofocus="autofocus" />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="my_dynamic_content" tabindex="1">Hello World</div>
```